# VBA script to search combination of values

Tags: vba, combinations

I hope someone can help me with the following.
I have a sheet with on each row a client/patient record (starting from row 3) and 56 colums of medical data (conditions, medication etc) to search in. I have a userform with several comboboxes to select the item or combination of items I search for. I made a script to search a combination of items. Problem is that the result is not even close of what the result should be.

```
Private Sub cmdCOMBI_Click()
Dim COMBIRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim cbo1 As String
Dim cbo2 As String
Dim cbo3 As String
Dim Par1 As Integer
Dim Par2 As Integer
Dim Par3 As Integer
Dim conb As Integer

LastRow = Worksheets("SOURCE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set COMBIRange = Worksheets("SOURCE").Range("A2:BO" & LastRow)

If Not cboINCL1.TEXT = "" Then
cbo1 = cboINCL1.Value
Par1 = 1
Else
cbo1 = "--"
Par1 = 0
End If

If Not cboINCL2.TEXT = "" Then
cbo2 = cboINCL2.Value
Par2 = 1
Else
cbo2 = "--"
Par2 = 0
End If

If Not cboINCL3.TEXT = "" Then
cbo3 = cboINCL3.Value
Par3 = 1
Else
cbo3 = "--"
Par3 = 0
End If

ParTotal = Par1 + Par2 + Par3
conb = 0

For iR = 3 To LastRow
    For iC = 11 To 67
      If Worksheets("SOURCE").Cells(iR, iC).Value = cbo1 Or Worksheets("SOURCE").Cells(iR, iC).Value = cbo2 Or Worksheets("SOURCE").Cells(iR, iC).Value = cbo3 Then
        INC = INC + 1
        End If
        Next iC

If INC = ParTotal Then
conb = conb + 1
End If
Next iR


  FormMENU.tboResIN.Value = conb
End Sub
```

Anyone an idee of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code by pressing F8 and determined where the errors occur?

Comment: No errors found using F8, but I figgered out that the script is counting the number of rows from the first match until the next match, and not the number of matches. Still don't know what the solution should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem myself. I forgot to declare INC back to 0 by the start of each new row.

```
For iR = 3 To LastRow
INC = 0
For iC = 11 To 67
```